# sitecoreContext from ComponentWithContextProps is undefined

Tags: jss, xm-cloud

Context item field data in `sitecoreContext` from `ComponentWithContextProps`, is undefined all the time.
ComponentWithContextProps is import of `lib/component-props`.
Below are the screen shot of code, lib, console log of browser.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I can see in the attached picture , we have to use sitecoreContext not with props .

```
You can access `sitecoreContext` by withSitecoreContext/useSitecoreContext
 * @example withSitecoreContext()(ContentBlock)
 * @example const { sitecoreContext } = useSitecoreContext()
```

First off all you need to import useSitecoreContext:

```
import {
  useSitecoreContext,
 } from '@sitecore-jss/sitecore-jss-nextjs';
```

and when you want to use it :

```
  const { sitecoreContext } = useSitecoreContext();

  return (
  <div className="sitecoreContext">
    <ul>
    <li>Sitecore item ID: {context.sitecoreContext.itemId}</li>
    <li>Sitecore item language: {context.sitecoreContext.language}</li>
    <li>Sitecore site name: {context.sitecoreContext.site?.name}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For the Context props to work, you have to wrap the component with `withSitecoreContext()`

Add the below lines in your component definition:

Import the withSitecoreContext,

```
import { withSitecoreContext } from '@sitecore-jss/sitecore-jss-nextjs';
```

And export the component like this,

```
export default withSitecoreContext()<ComponentWithContextProps>(MyComponent);
```

If you have other stuff in your props, extend the props with ComponentWithContextProps, and use it like this:

```
export type MyComponentProps {
  fields: {}
} & ComponentWithContextProps
```

And change the export to:

```
export default withSitecoreContext()<MyComponentProps>(MyComponent);
```